# Multiline message sending in C doesn't work

Tags: c, unix

I use message queue in C and sending information about all files (in current folder) from the **client** to server (MSGMAX defined as 4096).
Client code:

```
    int mq_id;
    struct { long type; char text[MSGMAX]; } mymsg;
    mq_id = msgget(12, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
FILE* p;
char str[MSGMAX];
p = popen("ls -l", "r");
while (fgets(str, MSGMAX, p)){ strcpy (mymsg.text, str); }
pclose(p);
mymsg.type = 1;
msgsnd(mq_id, &mymsg, sizeof(mymsg), IPC_NOWAIT);
}
```

In this part `mymsg.text` returns correct multline string (result of `ls -l`). But when I tried to print this string in **server** part, it retured only last line of whole string:

```
    int mq_id;
    struct { long type; char text[MSGMAX]; } mymsg;
    mq_id = msgget(12, 0);
    if (msgrcv(mq_id, &mymsg, sizeof(mymsg), 0, 0) < 0)
    perror("\nMsg error!");
    else
    printf("%s", mymsg.text);
```

How could I send `mymsg.text` completely, with all lines?

Comment: In `while (fgets(str, MSGMAX, p)){ strcpy (mymsg.text, str); }` you copy each line to the same  `mymsg.text`, so you end up sending the last line only. Either send each line individually or concat all lines, eg using strcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `while (fgets(str, MSGMAX, p)){ strcpy (mymsg.text, str); }`, you will override the contents of `mymsg.txt` with every new line read by `fgets`. I'd suggest to write something like...

```
strcpy(mymsg.text,"");
while (fgets(str, MSGMAX, p)){ strcat (mymsg.text, str); }
```

or you send the buffer to the server within the loop, i.e. sending every line read separately.

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful answer.